# Cannot add foreign key constraint (mysql-error-1215

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

this is the relational table where am getting my foreign keys from

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE(
 ENUM    DECIMAL(12)    NOT NULL,
 FNAME   VARCHAR(50)    NOT NULL,
 INITIALS VARCHAR(5)        NULL,
 LNAME    VARCHAR(50)    NOT NULL,
 DOB     DATE           NULL,
 BLDG     DECIMAL(3)    NOT NULL,
 STREET   VARCHAR(50)   NOT NULL,
 SUBURB   VARCHAR(50)   NOT NULL,
 STATE   VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
 ZIPCODE  DECIMAL(4)    NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEE_PKEY PRIMARY KEY(ENUM) );
```

and i want to create a new table called EMPNAME but have error when adding my foreign key constraint

```
CREATE TABLE EMPNAME(
 ENUM    DECIMAL(12)    NOT NULL,
 FNAME   VARCHAR(50)    NOT NULL,
 INITIALS VARCHAR(5)        NOT NULL,
 LNAME    VARCHAR(50)    NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT EMPNAME_PKEY PRIMARY KEY(ENUM),
    CONSTRAINT EMPNAME_FKEY FOREIGN KEY(ENUM, FNAME, INITIALS, LNAME) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(ENUM, FNAME, INITIALS, LNAME)
```

);

i dont get errors if i only set the primary key enum as foreign key but when i make all of the attributes foreign keys, i keep getting error.

thanks

Comment: Can you post the error too?

Comment: Why do you want to extract the names into a separate table? Two things to consider: 1) You can have two or more employees with the same name, but they are two different entities. 2) The storage space you gain by storing names in a separate table is negligible even when you have some duplicates names. An extra: you have an ID for the names, why are you using all the attribute fields to create an FK, what is wrong with the ID? (Using the attributes leads us back to the original question: why do you need that table?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reference columns must have indexes in order to be used as foreign keys, so add index(es) on these columns in your `employee` table:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
    ENUM DECIMAL (12) NOT NULL,
    FNAME VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    INITIALS VARCHAR (5) NULL,
    LNAME VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    DOB DATE NULL,
    BLDG DECIMAL (3) NOT NULL,
    STREET VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    SUBURB VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    STATE VARCHAR (5) NOT NULL,
    ZIPCODE DECIMAL (4) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEE_PKEY PRIMARY KEY (ENUM),
    INDEX `FKEYS` (ENUM, FNAME, INITIALS, LNAME)
);
```

Then you will be able to add your constraint into second table.

Comment: @Pred can you set a column that is null as unique too?

Comment: Yes, but it is not recommended. Null values are not equal, therefore multiple values are allowed, which is a  duplicate for a human being. (BTW, this is how the ansi standard defines the unique constraint.)